# How to namespace OOCSS classes with competing "scopes"?

Tags: html, css, namespaces, bem

I am aware that this is asking for a very opinionated answer, as are all naming-convention related questions, I guess.

I am using [Harry Roberts BEMIT naming convention](http://csswizardry.com/2015/08/bemit-taking-the-bem-naming-convention-a-step-further/), which augments BEM with prefixes/namespaces for object-oriented css.
That allows organizing classes into objects, using the `o-` prefix, for decoration-free design patterns like [the famous `media` object](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2010/06/25/the-media-object-saves-hundreds-of-lines-of-code/), and styled ui-components, using the `c-` prefix (plus some more).

Here is the (generic) example, that is often used in the context of explaining BEM, augmented with the problematic namespaces:

```
.o-btn {
  width: 100%;
}
```

And here the competing scope, targeting the same (bem)block

```
.c-btn {
  color: white;
  background: gray;
}
.c-btn--positive {
  background: green;
}
.c-btn--negative {
  background: red;
}
```

To quote the relevant part from Harry Roberts CSS Guidelines (*not enough cred to post 2nd link, sorry*):

> Above, we can see how the .btn {} class simply provides structural styling to an element, and doesn’t concern itself with any cosmetics. We supplement the .btn {} object with a second class, such as .btn--negative {} in order to give that DOM node specific cosmetics.

This explanation to me sounds like the exact justification to do as I did.
Still, it *feels* incorrect, to use two different namespaces on the same block, possibly confusing.

**Which namespace do I chose, if two of them are competing?**

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid of having different BEM entities on the same DOM node.

Actually pure BEM itself solves this issue with the help of mixes (see https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/#mix).

The idea is that you should keep `button` block as universal component with maximum reusability. Then you may add all the cosmetics with the help of `theme` modifier. And finally add positioning with a help of mix with parent's element (e.g. `form__submit`).

So you may end up with something like this:

```
<form class="form">
    <button class="button button--theme_awesome form__submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That was not my question, I may have phrased that confusingly. I am aware, that I can stack the classes in my example without a problem, however it feels wrong to use something that I have declared an object (o-prefix) and a component (c-prefix), with the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

You use what your projects require, in my case I much prefer the prefixed syntax (o-, c-, u-), because you're telling to your html elements what they are, a short example using sass syntax:

```
.c-button{
   &.c-button--dark{}
   &.c-button--orange{}
}
```

and you can overwrite bootstrap classes, for example, you don't have to take care about other classes, with this specification you are able to overwrite the default classes you might have, and you can have a mix of css classes in your hmtl element, for example:

```
<input type="text" class="btn btn-primary c-button c-button-dark" />
```